# Don't match if there's a "period" between "word" and "?"

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Perhaps he hadn't. [Perhaps he didn't?]

Perhaps he didn't.

[Perhaps he hadn't?]
```

I want to match the bits in brackets; sentences that start with "Perhaps" and end with a question mark.

I thought this regex would work: `Perhaps.*(?!=\.)\?`

However, what I'm getting is this:

```
[Perhaps he hadn't. Perhaps he didn't?]

Perhaps he didn't.

[Perhaps he hadn't?]
```

Why is this? And how to fix it?

https://regexr.com/5dfhs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negated character class like this:

```
/Perhaps[^.?]*\?/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regexr.com/5dfik)

To match complete word use:

```
/\bPerhaps[^.?]*\?/
```

And to avoid matching across lines use:

```
/\bPerhaps[^.?\r\n]*\?/
```

here `[^.?]` would match any character except `.` and `?`

**About your regex:**

`(?!=\.)` is actually wrong syntax for a negative lookahead. It just means don't match if we have a literal `=` and `.` ahead.

Even if you correct it to use `Perhaps.*(?!\.)\?` it will still not work because `(?!\.)` will only be applied for matching `?` and that will always succeed.

Though not recommended but if you really want to use a negative lookahead then use:

```
/Perhaps(?:(?!\.).)*\?/
```

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't the negative look forward working, though?

Comment: **Don't** use `/Perhaps(?:(?!\.).)*\?/`, if you need to avoid matching across lines, use `/Perhaps[^?.\n\r]*\?/`.

Comment: The `*?`quantifier after the excluding/negated character class is not needed. And mentioning the latter and thinking about punctuation one most probably has to recognize `?` too in addition to `.` (for matching the one liner *Perhaps he hadn't? Perhaps he didn't?* in a non greedy way) ... maybe even `!`. Thus the regex would read at least ... `/\bPerhaps[^.?]*\?/g`.

Comment: I wasn't really recommending use of `/Perhaps(?:(?!\.).)*\?/`. Just ponting out mistake in OP's attempted regex

Comment: Good point @PeterSeliger Answer updated with your suggestion